# Peculiar wrapping/not wrapping of text around floated divs in Chrome only

Tags: html, css

Recently (I cannot pinpoint the exact moment), Chrome started doing weird things to some of the divs on our site. Not all, just some. Which is awesome. (/sarcasm) Here's an example URL of where things are wacky: https://hightowerlowdown.org/article/we-have-a-moment-for-historic-progress-if-we-push-it/

*[Image: Here's a screenshot of correctly wrapped text around a floated div, at the beginning of the article.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToMk0.png)*

But, some of the other divs have giant breaks in them.

*[Image: This is further down the page, and text is incorrectly wrapped.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTS61.png)*

I can't figure out why this is happening. If I change the css of the paragraphs to overflow: hidden, all wrapped text extends beyond the floated div, as expected.

*[Image: Example of css changed to overflow: hidden;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDFaI.png)*

This is only happening in Chrome (tested on macOS Big Sur and Windows 10, v88 so far). Ideas? Halp?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha. I'm having difficulty pinpointing what code is making things go weird, so that seemed difficult, haha. I'll work on it now, thanks,

Comment: Could you please provide code?

Comment: @Deanna, Please no swearing on Stackoverflow in order to keep the site clean.

Comment: Please eliminate sarcasm.  it just muddies what your real quesition is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS file
https://hightowerlowdown.org/wp-content/themes/valenti-child/style.css?ver=1.0.0
at line 41:

```
p { 
    -moz-hyphens: none;
    -ms-hyphens: none;
    -webkit-hyphens: none;
    hyphens: none;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

Replace `hyphens: none` with `hyphens: unset`, or even remove this property at all.

Comment: oh MYGOD. Thank you so very much!

Comment: @Deanna, happy to help! Love your sarcasm =))